# Add a comma to the version of the program

Tags: c++

I was trying to change the version of a program, but I'm having difficulties I should add a number, for example: "5.50.1"
Currently it turns out to be 5.50

```
    #define SOFTWARE_VERSION        0x0F
    #define SOFTWARE_VERSION_BCD    0x0550

#if defined(SOFTWARE)
#define IS_SOFTWARE         1
#else
#define IS_SOFTWARE         0
#endif

#define MAKE_VERSION(aldebaran, fw, type) ((aldebarab&0xFF) | ((fw&0xffff)<<8) | ((type&0x1)<<24))
```

Comment: I what context are your defines used? I recommend to replace the define with either a `const std::string SOFTWARE_VERSION = 5.50.1` or even better with a propper get function.

Comment: sorry, but the minimal editor, does not allow me to put the "<code>" could you tell me how to do? I added it in the first post.

Comment: Please don't use those preprocessor macros (MAKE_VERSION). You can use a constexp (no runtime overhead) and you are type save.

Comment: Your `MAKE_VERSION` macro doesn't return `5.50`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to add an extra build number. From 5.50 to 5.50.1
Currently if set 0x05501, the version number that comes out on the screen is 55.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using visual studio as the compiler, then the resource file (.rc) can be accessed by the resource id which is defined in resource.h. The version number can be retrieved/modified/saved as a string resource (std::string, TCHAR, CString etc).